# Java DB (JDBC) SQL - Lexical Error , encountered "@" (64) after ""

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

I have compiled my JavaFX application and when I try to take the data from the UI and update the database I get this error:

```
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Lexical Error at line 1 , column 105. Encountered "@" (64) after : ""
at org.apache.derby.client.am.SQLExceptionFactory.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.client.am.ClientStatement.execute(Unknown Source)
at Query.generateOperation(Query.java:45)
at AdminAccount.addAdmin(AdminAccount.java:27)
at Root.lambdaExpression(Root.java:89)
```

This is the code which is referenced for Query ->

```
public void generateOperation(String query) {
    try {
        Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
        statement.execute(query) // line raised by compiler
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This is the code which is referenced for AdminAccount ->

```
public void addAdmin(String username, String password, String email) {
    int id = generateId(); // return random number for id
    String values = id + ", " + username + ", " + password + ", " + email;
    DB.generateOperation("insert into APP.ADMINDETAILS (ID , USERNAME , PASSWORD , EMAIL) values (" + values + ")"); // DB is the Query object I use to interact with the database . This line is raised by the compiler
}
```

This is the code which is called by the user interface

```
submit.setOnAction(e -> {
    if (...) {
         adminAccount.addAdmin(usernameEntry.getText(), passwordEntry.getText(), emailEntry.getText()) ; // this is the line raised by compiler
    }
});
```

What should I amend to this code so that I don't get the lexical error when parsing the SQL statement. I think there is trouble parsing the email entry as the compiler references the "@" symbol. Should I be using another method for constructing SQL statements?

Comment: Why don't you use PreparedStatements?

Comment: Don't concatenate user input into SQL strings. Use a `PreparedStatement` Apart from being much more secure it also magically solves your problem

Comment: OK first off.. DO NOT APPEND plain text to a query! 
This error is due to a classical case of input not being sanitized

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html

Comment: (The "magic" being that you are not putting quotes around the SQL string literals ... and a `PreparedStatements` avoids the need to do that.  As well as avoiding the gnarly SQL injection problems that arise with SQL query string bashing.)

Answer (score 1):

The correct way of doing things is to **NOT** concatenate values into a query string. You need to use `PreparedStatement`, with placeholders for each value you want to set, and then explicitly set each value before you execute.

Given your code, you would need to do something like:

```
try (PreparedStatement insertStatement = connection.prepareStatement(
        "insert into APP.ADMINDETAILS (ID, USERNAME, PASSWORD, EMAIL) values (?, ?, ?, ?)")) {
    insertStatement.setInt(1, id);
    insertStatement.setString(2, username);
    // Do NOT do this in a real application, hash is with a password hash algorithm
    insertStatement.setString(3, password); 
    insertStatement.setString(4, email);

    insertStatement.executeUpdate();
}
```

The question marks in the statement are the placeholders for values, and using the `setXXX` methods ensures the values are correctly set before execution. This makes your query safe because it will prevent SQL injection.